# How to use console.profile in a WinJS enabled app?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I'm currently working on an app using javascript which has a recursive function. I would like to use console.profile in order to inspect it, but I can't find exactly how to get the output of the profile session.

I start my session with the following;:

```
console.profile("sessionName")
```

But the following doesn't log anything to console on my machine:

```
console.profileEnd("sessionName");
```

The following doesn't seem to catch anything either

```
var d = console.profileEnd("sessionName");
```

How should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Visual Studio 2012 profiler with Debug\Start performance analysis paused, and then unpause it from the point in your program you wish to take a profile.

Comment: That is one way that works, thanks. But when working with WinJS apps, the console object is available from the global scope. It has a profile(...) function, so maybe it's there just as a dummy?

Comment: I *think* (although I've not tried) that if you start with the profiler as I said, *then* those functions will do the "right thing". *think*